# How to set Kotlin version

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin, jitsi

Hello I'm facing the following error when building the android portion of https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet

> 'let((T) -> R): R' is only available since Kotlin 1.3.50 and cannot be used in Kotlin 1.3

on line [Screen.kt#L156](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/blob/6c87d7749ec62fbb51fb4ec50af1fa8733ebae86/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/Screen.kt#L156)

In Android Studio settings shows using Kotlin 1.6 in the compiler settings and when I set a project variable `kotlinVersion` in `build.gradle` to 1.6.10 I still get the same error.

Comment: why don't you try to use keywords for the link instead of just randomly pasting it? It makes it look congested. You can use it this way -> [Your text here](yourUrlHere). This is a sample test -> [Click here to open stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per the codebase, I observed that the [react-native-screens](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/tree/6c87d7749ec62fbb51fb4ec50af1fa8733ebae86/android) project is using `Kotlin` for their development. Whereas in you project, you are implementing your project in pure `Java`.

So, to use this library, you would need to add kotlin support in your project. To do so, please add following code snippet in [your project level `build.gradle`](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/master/android/build.gradle)

1. In `buildscript`'s `dependencies` block add kotlin classpath:

```
// Project build.gradle file.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.10'
    ...
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

2. Then apply `kotlin-android` plugin to all the required module by adding following in required module's `build.gradle` file.

```
plugins {
    ...
    id 'kotlin-android'
}
```

You can find the same implementation in the library at [react-native-screens build.gradle Line 12](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/blob/6c87d7749ec62fbb51fb4ec50af1fa8733ebae86/android/build.gradle#L12) and [react-native-screens build.gradle Line 23](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/blob/6c87d7749ec62fbb51fb4ec50af1fa8733ebae86/android/build.gradle#L23).

Ref: https://developer.android.com/kotlin/add-kotlin

Comment: why don't you try to use keywords for the link instead of just randomly pasting it? It makes it look congested. You can use it this way -> [Your text here](yourUrlHere). This is a sample test -> [Click here to open stackoverflow](https://www.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: @Sambhav.K updated the comment. Thanks for the feedback. :)

Comment: ok. its better now. But the links at the bottom can also be shortened

Comment: I tried this but it said it couldn't find `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'` but when I change it to `apply plugin: 'kotlin'` it says `The 'java' plugin has been applied, but it is not compatible with the Android plugins.`

Comment: OK only applying step one is what works.

Answer (score 6):

Update android/build.gradle as follows:

```
{
  buildscript {
    ext {
      ...
      kotlinVersion = "1.5.31"
  }
   dependencies { 
  [enter image description here][1] classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31"
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

In buildscript's dependencies block add kotlin classpath:

```
    // Project build.gradle file.
    buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.10'
        ...
        dependencies {
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        }
    }
```

Then apply kotlin-android plugin to all the required module by adding following in required module's build.gradle file.

```
    plugins {
        ...
        id 'kotlin-android'
    }
```